# Parsing Plain JSON Array in Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, json

I want to parse a plain JSON array like:

```
{
    "ns": [
        [
            "1364987475027",
            "Alert1",
            "001"
        ],
        [
            "1364987475042",
            "Alert2",
            "001"
        ],
        [
            "1364987475058",
            "Alert4",
            "001"
        ]
    ]
}
```

To get the array in simple arrays of string. I found many posts with JSON dictionary arrays. But in this case the JSON is not having keys for the values.
Kindly help.

Comment: I mentioned that the posts are for keyed values and not for plain arrays @jv42

Comment: Have you looked at the first question linked? It contains a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Answer :** [`NSJSONSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

`NSJSONSerialization` class can be used to convert JSON to Foundation objects and Foundation objects to JSON. In your case, you should use `-JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` of `NSJSONSerialization` class to retrieve a Foundation object from given JSON data.

---

**Sample Code :**

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray *fetchedArr = [json objectForKey:@"ns"];
```

Answer (score 2):

The `NSJSONSerialization` method `JSONObjectWithData:options:error` can to that. You will get a dictionary with one value for the key "ns" and the value will be an array of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

And the description shows what you are looking for

```
   NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSArray *fetchedArr = [json objectForKey:@"ns"];

    for (NSArray *arr in fetchedArr) {
        [arr description];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 NSError *error = NULL;
NSData* data = [yourJsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                  JSONObjectWithData:data
                                  options:kNilOptions
                                  error:&error];
NSArray *resultArray = [json objectForKey:@"ns"];//resultArray contains array type objects...
```

I think it will be helpful to you.