# How can i fetch value from Json response in Objective -C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, ios5

I have a problem with fetching data from Json response.

Here is an example data structure :

```
(
     {
        AT = "<null>";
        DId = 0;
        DO = 0;
        PLId = 33997;
        PdCatList =  (
                       {
                PLId = 33997;
                PPCId = 0;

                pdList = (
                      {
                        IsDis = 0;
                        IsPS = 0;
                        IsT = 1;
                        PA = 1;
                        PCId = 119777;
                     }
                );
            }
        );
        PdId = 0;
        SId = 0;
        Sec = 1;
    },
     {
        AT = "<null>";
        DId = 0;
        DO = 11;
        Dis = 0;
        PLId = 34006;
        PdCatList =   (
                {

                PLId = 34006;
                PPCId = 0;
                pdList =  (
                       {
                        IsDis = 0;
                        IsPS = 0;
                        IsT = 1;
                        PA = 1;
                        PCId = 119830;
                       },
                       {
                        IsDis = 0;
                        IsPS = 0;
                        IsT = 1;
                        PA = 1;
                        PCId = 119777;
                       }
                   );
              },

             {
                PLId = 33997;
                PPCId = 0;
                pdList = (
                      {
                        IsDis = 0;
                        IsPS = 0;
                        IsT = 1;
                        PA = 1;
                        PCId = 119777;
                     }
                );
            }

        );
        PdId = 0;
        SId = 0;
        Sec = 1;
    },
)
```

how would i parse the resulting Structure ?
I would like to get a list of values directly. What if i have several values in a tupel for example performer PdCatList, pdList. How would i access those values?
Can anyone help me

Thank's

my code is

```
NSError *error;
    Array1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    for(int i=0;i<[Array1 count];i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict1 = [Array1 objectAtIndex:i];

        NSLog(@"Array1.....%@",dict1);

        Array2=[dict1 valueForKey:@"PdCatList"];

        for(int i=0;i<[Array2 count];i++)
        {

            NSDictionary *dict2 = [Array2 objectAtIndex:i];

            NSLog(@"Array2.....%@",dict2);

            Array3=[dict2 valueForKey:@"pdList"];

            for(int i=0;i<[Array3 count];i++)
            {

                NSDictionary *dict3 = [Array3 objectAtIndex:i];

                NSLog(@"Array3.....%@",dict3);

            }


        }


    }
```

Comment: I saw your questions and found that you always make a new question for every new `JSON` response.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<[Array1 count];i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict1 = [Array1 objectAtIndex:i];
        Array2=[dict1 valueForKey:@"PdCatList"];
        for(int i=0;i<[Array2 count];i++)
        {
            NSDictionary *dict2 = [Array2 objectAtIndex:i];
            Array3=[dict2 valueForKey:@"pdList"];
            for(int i=0;i<[Array3 count];i++)
            {
                NSDictionary *dict3 = [Array3 objectAtIndex:i];
            }   
        }   
    }

Comment: Take a look at the Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17025824/1603072. It may help you to understand what a JSON Parsing is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
NSError *error;
Array1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

for(int i=0;i<[Array1 count];i++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict1 = [Array1 objectAtIndex:i];

    ATArray =[dict1 valueForKey:@"AT"];
    DIdArray =[dict1 valueForKey:@"DId"];
    DOArray =[dict1 valueForKey:@"DO"];
    PLIdArray =[dict1 valueForKey:@"PLId"];

    etc...

    Array2=[dict1 valueForKey:@"PdCatList"];

    for(int i=0;i<[Array2 count];i++)
    {

        NSDictionary *dict2 = [Array2 objectAtIndex:i];

        PLIdArray =[dict2 valueForKey:@"PLId"];
        PPCIdArray =[dict2 valueForKey:@"PPCId"];

        etc…

        Array3=[dict2 valueForKey:@"pdList"];

        for(int i=0;i<[Array3 count];i++)
        {

            NSDictionary *dict3 = [Array3 objectAtIndex:i];

            IsDisArray =[dict3 valueForKey:@"IsDis"];
            IsPSArray =[dict3 valueForKey:@"IsPS"];
            IsTArray =[dict3 valueForKey:@"IsT"];
            PAArray =[dict3 valueForKey:@"PA"];
            PCIdArray =[dict3 valueForKey:@"PCId"];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you require here is to understand what a JSON response is rather than the Answer to get the values of some objects from your JSON response.

If you want some detail explanation about JSON Parsing then you can take a look at [NSJSONSerialization Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Everything is given there or you can take a look at my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15786207/1603072).

---

Understand the Concept. It depends on what you have inside your `JSON`. If it's an Array ( Values inside `[ ]`) then you have to save in `NSArray`, if it's a Dictionary ( Values inside `{ }`) then save as `NSDictionary` and if you have single values like string , integer, double then you have to save them using appropriate Objective-C Data types.

For some simple details with example , you can check my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17025824/1603072) from this question.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSONKit(https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit):

```
NSString *yourJSONString = ...
NSArray *responseArray = [yourJSONString objectFromJSONString];
for(NSDictionary *responseDictionary in responseArray)
{
    NSString *atString = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"AT"];
    ...
    NSArray *pdCatListArray = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"PdCatList"];
    ...here you can get all values you want,if you want to get more details in PdCatList,use for in pdCatListArray ,you can do what you want.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use following method:


NSDictionary *mainDict;
SBJSON *jsonParser = [[SBJSON alloc]init];
    if([[jsonParser objectWithString:responseString] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        mainDict=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[jsonParser objectWithString:responseString]];
    }

NSDictionary *firstDict=[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[mainDict valueForKey:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to **add JSON framework** which is parse string into NSDictionary.
Use zip file from [here](https://github.com/downloads/stig/json-framework/SBJson_3.0.1.zip)

1. Open Folder and rename Classes folder to "JSON".
2. Copy **JSON Folder** and include in your project.
3. **Import header** file like below in controller where you want to parse JSON String.

   ```js
   #import "SBJSON.h"
   #import "NSString+SBJSON.h"
   ```
4. Now, Parse your response string in to **NSDictionary** like below.

   ```js
   NSMutableDictionary *dictResponse = [strResponse JSONValue];
   ```

Comment: Dear editors and edit reviewers, I just learned about this, but you have to [indent code 8 spaces within a list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30046/how-do-i-include-a-code-block-right-after-a-list-without-it-turning-into-a-block)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)
to access the nested properties in the JSON. You need to know about [KVC and dot syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-SW2) and [Collection operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE)

Frameworks that map JSON to objects, such as [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/) rely heavily on KVC.

Following your sample, you could get a list of all PdCatList objects:

```
//sample data
NSArray *json = @[
                  @{@"PLId" : @33997,
                    @"PdCatList" : @{@"PLId": @33998,
                                     @"PPCId" : @1,
                                    @"pdList" : @{
                                      @"PCId" : @119777
                                      }}
                        },
                  @{@"PLId" : @33999,
                    @"PdCatList" : @{@"PLId": @4444,
                                     @"PPCId" : @0,
                                     @"pdList" : @{
                                             @"PCId" : @7777
                                             }}}
                    ];

//KVC
NSArray *pdCatLists = [json valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.PdCatList"];
```

With this you can, for example, make a very basic object mapping (which does not take care of relationships)

**In PdCatList.h**

```
@interface PdCatList : NSObject
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *PLId;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *PPCId;
+ (instancetype)listWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)aDictionary;
@end
```

**In PdCatList.m**

```
@implementation PdCatList
- (void)setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key
{
    @try {
        [super setValue:value forUndefinedKey:key];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"error setting undefined key: %@, exception: %@", key, exception);
    };
}
+ (id)listWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)aDictionary
{
    PdCatList *result = [[self alloc] init];
    [result setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:aDictionary];
    return result;
}
@end
```

**After getting the json object**

```
NSArray *pdCatLists = [json valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.PdCatList"];

[pdCatLists enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    PdCatList *each = [PdCatList listWithDictionary:obj];
}];
```

However, If what you want is just to flatten the json, you must use recursion and create a category similar to the following.

**In NSJSONSerialization+FlattenedJSON.h**

```
@interface NSJSONSerialization (FlattenedJSON)
+ (void)FlattenedJSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data completionSuccessBlock:(void(^)(id aJson))onSuccess failure:(void(^)(NSError *anError))onFailure;
@end
```

**In NSJSONSerialization+FlattenedJSON.m**

```
#import "NSJSONSerialization+FlattenedJSON.h"

@implementation NSJSONSerialization (FlattenedJSON)
+ (void)FlattenedJSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data completionSuccessBlock:(void (^)(id))onSuccess failure:(void (^)(NSError *))onFailure
{
    NSError *error;
    id object = [self JSONObjectWithData:data
                     options:kNilOptions
                       error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        onFailure(error);
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self flatten:object
              inArray:result];
        onSuccess([result copy]);
    }
}
+ (void)flatten:(id)anObject inArray:(NSMutableArray *)anArray
{
    if ([anObject isKindOfClass:NSDictionary.class])
    {
        [((NSDictionary *)anObject) enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
            [self flatten:obj inArray:anArray];
        }];
    }
    else if ([anObject isKindOfClass:NSArray.class])
    {
        [((NSArray *)anObject) enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            [self flatten:obj inArray:anArray];
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [anArray addObject:anObject];
    }
}
@end
```