# parse JSON string to NSDictionary into array of objects Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, xcode7

I am new in objective-c . They are many solutions for my problem but I am failed to solve   .I am trying to parsing a JSON  and i successfully  done.  Code are bellow :

```
     NSString *urlString   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",homePagesNews];
 // The Openweathermap JSON responder
        NSURL *url            = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSData *GETReply      = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
        NSDictionary *res     = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GETReply options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves|| NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",res);
```

Output are :

```
{
    "item_id": "102949",
    "featured_image": "http://198.72.115.125/~pratidin/assets/news_images/2015/10/05/thumbnails/VC_mohit_ul_alam_pic.jpg",
    "main_news_url": "http://198.72.115.125/~pratidin/api/detailnews/102949",
    "title": "'শিক্ষকতা চর্চাহীন একটা তন্ত্র গোষ্ঠিতে পরিণত হয়েছে'",
    "datetime": "2015-10-05 20:13:44",
    "summery": "&#39;শিক্ষক সমাজ একেবারে চর্চাহীন একটা তন্ত্র&#8230;",
    "main_url": "http://198.72.115.125/~pratidin/api/categorynews/4"
  },
  {
    "item_id": "102198",
    "featured_image": "http://198.72.115.125/~pratidin/assets/news_images/2015/09/05/thumbnails/1438144816_104634.png.jpg",
    "main_news_url": "http://198.72.115.125/~pratidin/api/detailnews/102198",
    "title": "সাকার ছোট ছেলে হুম্মাম কারাগারে",
    "datetime": "2015-09-05 20:23:17",
    "summery": "রাজধানীর গুলশানে মারামারি অভিযোগে দায়ের&#8230;",
    "main_url": "http://198.72.115.125/~pratidin/api/categorynews/4"
  },
  {
    "item_id": "102180",
    "featured_image": "http://198.72.115.125/~pratidin/assets/news_images/2015/09/05/thumbnails/1_104567.jpg",
    "main_news_url": "http://198.72.115.125/~pratidin/api/detailnews/102180",
    "title": "আজ বীরশ্রেষ্ঠ নূর মোহাম্মদের ৪৪তম শাহাদতবার্ষিকী",
    "datetime": "2015-09-05 14:00:19",
    "summery": "মুক্তিযুদ্ধের রণাঙ্গণের সাহসী সন্তান&#8230;",
    "main_url": "http://198.72.115.125/~pratidin/api/categorynews/4"
  }
```

I want to get this value title,datetime,main_url . I check bellow mention
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786109/parsing-plain-json-array-in-objective-c) .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this way `NSLog(@"%@",[[res objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"item_id"]);`

Comment: It is already an array... although your output must have been enclosed between two square brackets `[]`. Is it exactly what you see in your debug console using NSLog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code to get value

```
NSMutableArray *res     = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GETReply options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves|| NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",res);
// get item id
NSLog(@"item-id :%@",[[res objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"item_id"]);
NSLog(@"datetime %@",[[res objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"datetime"]);
NSLog(@"main_url %@",[[res objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"main_url"]);
```

or get all value from response

```
for (int i=0; i< res.count; i++){
    NSLog(@"item-id :%@",[[res objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"item_id"]);
    NSLog(@"datetime %@",[[res objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"datetime"]);
    NSLog(@"main_url %@",[[res objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"main_url"]);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot .. it works perfectly .. i need  one more help .. you u kindly do me favour

Comment: how i will show this data in my custom UITableView..contact = contactsArray[indexPath.row];
    
    NSString *firstName = contact[@"title"];
    NSString *lastName = contact[@"summery"];
    NSString *imageName = contact[@"featured_image"];
    
    NSLog(@"Now : %@",firstName);
    
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName ];
    
    customCell.customFirstNameLabel.text = firstName;
    customCell.customLastnameLabel.text = lastName;
    customCell.customImageView.image =image;

Comment: you can show data this way -> `customCell.customFirstNameLabel.text = [[res objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];` @FerrakkemBhuiyan

Comment: @FerrakkemBhuiyan sorry I am in company. goole it. every thing hehe.

Comment: @FerrakkemBhuiyan refer this example http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Your response is collection of dictionary values, so you need to store your response in NSArray object like below :

```
    NSArray *res     = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GETReply options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves|| NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

To fetch attributes, use below code:

```
    NSDictionary * dict = [res objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"title = %@", [dict objectForKey:@"title"]);
```